# What is the error in this SQL update stament

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, qsqlquery

I have the method that do update to data base table
but when I invoke it I have an exception "Incorrect syntax near '('."

Here is the method

```
 internal Boolean update(int customerID,int followingID, string fullName, string idNumber, string address, string tel, string mobile1, string mobile2, string email, string customerComment, DateTime timeStamp)
     {
         string sqlStatment = "update customers set (followingID, fullName,idNumber,address,tel,mobile1,mobile2,email,customerComment,timeStamp) = (@followingID, @fullName,@idNumber,@address,@tel,@mobile1,@mobile2,@email,@customerComment,@timeStamp) where customerID=@customerID";

         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
         con.ConnectionString = connection;
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatment, con);

         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerID", customerID);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@followingID", followingID);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullName", fullName);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idNumber", idNumber);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel", tel);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile1", mobile1);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile2", mobile2);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerComment", customerComment);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeStamp", timeStamp);


         bool success = false;
         try
         {

             con.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             success = true;

         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {

             success = false;
             //throw ex;
         }
         finally
         {
             con.Close();
         }
         return success;
     }
```

and here is the database table columns

[image: Customers table]

Comment: UPDATE sql query syntax is wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UPDATE` syntax is wrong..

Try

```
string sqlStatment = "UPDATE customers SET followingID= @followingID, fullName=@fullName, idNumber=@idNumber,address=@address,tel=@tel,mobile1=@mobile1,mobile2=@mobile2,email=@email,customerComment=@customerComment,timeStamp=@timeStamp WHERE customerID=@customerID"
```

Answer (score 5):

Your Syntax error is incorrect.Please refer the link for **[Update Query Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)**

```
update customers 
set 
followingID= @followingID, 
fullName=@fullName,
idNumber=@idNumber,
address=@address,
tel=@tel,
mobile1=@mobile1,
mobile2=@mobile2,
email=@email,
customerComment=@customerComment,
timeStamp=@timeStamp
where customerID=@customerID
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `sql update` statement is wrong. For more about update statement [see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hwekas8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
     string sqlStatment = "update customers set followingID=@followingID,
          fullName=@fullName,idNumber=@idNumber,address=@address,tel=@tel,
          mobile1=@mobile1,mobile2=@mobile2,email=@email,
          customerComment=@customerComment,timeStamp=@timeStamp
        where customerID=@customerID";
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see the Update statement syntax:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

you cannot bulk update values in the table

Answer (score 1):

Never seen an update statement like that - normally it'd be `set followingid = @followingid, fullname = @fullname` etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error, update statement is used like this

```
update customers set followingID=@followingID,
fullName=@fullName,
idNumber=@idNumber,
address=@address,
tel=@tel,
mobile1=@mobile1,
mobile2=@mobile2,
email=@email,
customerComment=@customerComment,
timeStamp=@timeStamp
where customerID=@customerID
```